# read socket in loop

Tags: java, c, sockets, network-programming

I'm writing sockets client-server program. Client is in java and server in C. 
I would like to read from file in server and line by line write is to client.
fragment of client:

```
while(!(answer = input.readLine()).equals("end")) {
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
```

server:

```
char* line;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;
FILE* out;
while((read = getline(&line, &len, out))!=-1){
    write(fd, line, read);
}
write(fd, "end", 3);
```

I get on output everyone lines from file, but It never go out from loop. 
What I want to do?
When client connect server read lines from fine, write it to client and now client can add new lines to file (which will be reading by other clients)
Anyone knows how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

C `read()` returns zero at end of stream, and you aren't testing for it.

Java `readLine()` returns null at end of stream, and you aren't testing for that either.

Comment: but I dont wont ending stream. I would like read data from file and do something else

Comment: I was trying check by write(fd, "end", 3); but It doesnt work. In server loop is end but in client I cant read "end"

Comment: You want to read the data from the file and stop doing so at end of stream, and I have told you how to do that. You can't read "end" in the client because you are never sending it, because you are never getting out of the file-reading loop, for the reason I have also given you. There is nothing stopping you from doing something else afterwards.

Comment: When I change for while((answer = input.readLine())!=null) and while((read = getline(&line, &len, out))!=0) I get infinite loop. I dont want close descriptor of connection and input.readLine()!=null will be only when connection is close.

I getting out in server loop but I cant get it in client

Comment: I didn't tell you to change the `readLine()` loop in that specific way. I did say you have to check for null, and so you do, but there is nothing stopping you from exiting that loop at `"end"` as well. NB the `read()` loop should be `while ... > 0` so as to stop both at end of stream and an error,

Comment: There is no `read()` call in the original question, so the answer does not make sense. The above code calls [`getline()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) which returns -1 on end-of-file condition.

Comment: @apangin Must have been edited out in the first 5 minutes. It was certainly there. In any case the part about `readLine()` most certainly makes sense.